# Bash script - split String in two variables

Tags: string, bash, shell

In a Bash script I want to split a string into two other strings based on the last "/" it contains.

In a situation where the given string is `"Example/Folder/Structure"`, I would like to create two other strings with the following values:

```
string 1 = "Example/Folder"
string 2 = "Structure"
```

I'm trying to create a script to get a slather coverage report for a given folder in an iOS app. Although I have minimal knowledge of Bash, I was able to get it to work when the given folder is located in the root of the project. Now I want to make the script able to handle paths so that I can get the report also for subfolders, and for that I need to differentiate the desired folder from the rest of the path.

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried, and the (wrong) output generated by your code; consider reviewing [bash parameter expansion](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), paying particular attention to the `##` / `#` / `%%` / `%` pattern specifiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basename(1), dirname(1):

```
path=a/b/c
basename=$(basename "$path") # c
dirname=$(dirname "$path")   # a/b
```

Prefix/suffix removal:

```
path=a/b/c
basename=${path##*/}         # c
dirname=${path%/*}           # a/b
```

- Prefix/suffix removal is sufficient in some circumstances, and faster because it's native shell.
- dirname/basename commands are slower (especially many paths in a loop etc) but handle more variable input or directory depth.
- Eg. `dirname "file"` prints `.`, but suffix removal would print `file`. `dirname /dir` prints `/`, but suffix removal prints empty string; dirname also handles contiguous slashes (`dirname a//b`); `basename a/b/` prints `b`, but prefix removal prints empty string.
- If you *know* the structure is always 3 slashes (`a/b/c`), it may be safe to use prefix/suffix removal. But here I would use basename and dirname.
- Also think about whether a better approach is to change the working directory with `cd`, so you can just refer to current directory with `.` (there's also `$PWD` and `$OLDPWD`).

Comment: `dirname=${path%"$basename"}` is safer than `dirname=${path%/*}`